# How can I automatically preselect/preload an FCKEditor template?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

The [template documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Templates) works great, it's just that I would like to have a template preloaded by default.